# Performing joins with array of foreign keys works for only one array but not two in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which performs joins on an array of foreign keys, and this query works (see below). But when I try to perform joins for two separate arrays for foreign keys, it fails, and gives me this error, which is strange because `unnested` is previously accessible and all I've done is duplicate some of the code.

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "unnested"
LINE 9:      ON s.id = unnested.color
                       ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "unnested", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Working query:

```sql
SELECT e.*,
      JSON_AGG(ARRAY[s.*] ORDER BY order_column) AS apples
    FROM fruits as e, 
        UNNEST(e.symbols) with ORDINALITY AS unnested(color, order_column)
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) tree.* FROM tree) AS s ON s.id = unnested.color
    WHERE e.cond = TRUE
    GROUP BY e.id
```

Not working query:

```sql
SELECT e.*,
      JSON_AGG(ARRAY[s.*] ORDER BY order_column) AS apples,
      JSON_AGG(ARRAY[s.*]) AS oranges
    FROM fruits as e, 
        UNNEST(e.symbols) with ORDINALITY AS unnested(color, order_column),
        UNNEST(e.symbols_used) with ORDINALITY AS unnested2(color2, order_column2)
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) tree.* FROM tree) AS s
        ON s.id = unnested.color
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) tree.* FROM tree) AS s_used
        ON s_used.id = unnested2.color2
    WHERE e.cond = TRUE
    GROUP BY e.id
```

Comment: Use `join lateral`

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` but no ORDER BY?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Tried `join lateral` on both and on each join statements but still getting the same error

Comment: Sorry, but I have to chime in with the unasked-for advice: don't store foreign keys in arrays.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe np! all advice welcome. what's a better way to do it?

Comment: To model an m:n relationship between two entities, use a third table that only contains two foreign keys to the related tables. Each row in that table relates two entries in the referenced tables.